# What does "here goes nothing" mean?

Tags: expressions

I regularly hear  the phrase **"here goes nothing"**. For example when someone starts up a computer after doing stupid configuration and is not sure if it will start.

But I'm not sure about what it means, or when to use this sentence. Should I use it just before doing something stupid or when I'm uncertain while doing it?

Comment: Hi. This seems answerable with a dictionary (M-W: [here goes nothing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/here%20goes%20nothing)). If the dictionary was not helpful, please [edit] your post to explain why you're still confused. It's also helpful to include any research you do to answer your own questions. See the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you say it **before** you attempt something risky, dangerous, something you are very likely to fail at.

It means roughly "I'm sure nothing good will come of it, but I'm going to do it anyway".